# asp.net UpdatePanel not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, ajax.net

Im using an UpdatePanel to refresh a datagrid with some search results but is not working and the whole page goes in postback.  i hope somebody can help me, cant get this to work right. . Thanks. Here is my code:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="pageTitle" valign="top">
                        <twc:LocalizedLiteral Text="CRMcontxt6" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                    <tr align="left" style="background-color: #9bbbe3">
                        <td align="left" colspan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSearch" Height="15" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="11"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox Width="500px" ID="Search" autoclick="BtnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="boxDesign" />
                            <asp:LinkButton  ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="save" />
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                   <asp:datagrid id="searchresults" runat="server">
           </ContentTemplate>

             <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnSearch" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you added a scriptmanager to the page?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a familiar .NET Bug. Setting ClientIDMode="AutoID" on the LinkButton should fix it (by the way, you can remove the trigger.  It's not needed).

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions:

a. Try Giving `UpdateMode = Conditional` in the UpdatePanel and try ( when you give triggers
you must define this )

b. Try removing the `<table>`, and replace it with `<div>`, sometimes Update Panels are not friendly with the table tag.

c. If above does not work, first try removing the triggers, and the update mode condition and see whether that works. Because if that doesn't work, it means something wrong with the content inside the update panel. You may want to start with some controls to drill down your problem.

d. I see user controls getting called - check if you have update panel inside those user controls placed properly.

Comment: Hi, i tried your proposed solutions without getting this control to work as its supposed to. Im going to check the content inside the update panel as you suggest. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Use this in UpdatePanel:

```
UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your HTML source does not have 2 or more `<form>` tags. An asp.net page is supposed to ordinarily have only one `<form>` tag.

Though this question has been long asked without an answer so far, I faced a similar problem, but discovered the cause of the update panel not working:

When you have a `<form>` tag in some piece of HTML and then insert that HTML fragment inside the already existing `<form>` tag of your master page, you get into problems. Each time the child page of the master page is run, and the submit button is clicked, the code the button is supposed to run wont execute. Instead the whole  page gets refreshed despite the update panel, and it might also add a query string in the URL of the page.

The nested `<form>` tag  of the master page is at the cause of this. As soon as you remove the extra `<form>` tag everything should work fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hi, I have edited your answer to be less of story-telling and put it in a format that is more to the point, and less tied to your experience. This is more helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the trigger event. Your trigger should look like this

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnSearch" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Don't forget to set the `UpdateMode` attrivute of the update panel to `Conditional`

Here is a reference :: [Using Triggers in an UpdatePanel in ASP.NET 4.0 C#](http://v4.programminghelp.com/controls/using-triggers-in-an-updatepanel-in-asp-net-4-0-c/)

Comment: Thanks for answering Krihandu. If you look at the bottom of my code you can see that i included the trigger event. i tried to put in the Eventname "Click", "OnClick" ecc but nothing works. Im using other extenders on the same page and they work fine. Any clues? tnx

Comment: You don;t need the trigger for controls that are already within the UpdatePanel - if I remember well. Also your datagrid tag is not closed

Comment: Don't forget to set the `UpdateMode` attribute of the update panel to `Conditional` . BTW I can't find any  trigger event in your code.

Comment: Ive tried with and without trigger event but when i click on the button btnSearch it creates a postback on the whole page. im begining to think its a bug